# Pivot table into cross reference table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a list of students who are assigned into groups 4 different groups for 3 weeks or more. Here is the table.

| student | week 1 | week 2 | week 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| D | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| E | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| F | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| G | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| H | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| I | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| J | 2 | 2 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |

I want to pivot that table and see how many times a student worked with another student in a group.
For example, student A worked with student J twice and student B worked with student F three times, whereas B and C never worked together.

How can I generate a pivot table in excel like the one below? The values in the table below show many times a student has been in the same group with another student.

| FIELD1 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | - |  | 2 |  | 2 |  |  |  | 2 |  |
| B | - | - |  |  |  | 3 |  |  |  | 3 |
| C | - | - | - |  |  |  | 2 |  |  |  |
| D | - | - | - | - |  |  |  | 2 |  |  |
| E | - | - | - | - | - |  |  |  | 2 |  |
| F | - | - | - | - | - | - |  |  |  | 3 |
| G | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |  |  |  |
| H | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |  |  |
| I | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |  |
| J | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter this formula in G2 and copy down and across. It should work in most versions of Excel but may need to be entered as an array formula in non-365 versions.

```
=IF(ROW(A1)>=COLUMN(A1),"-",
SUM(--(INDEX($B$2:$D$11,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$11,0),0)=INDEX($B$2:$D$11,MATCH(G$1,$A$2:$A$11,0),0))))
```

[image]

Agree with @EEM that this is vulnerable to insertions and deletions, maybe something like this is safer:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($G$2)>=COLUMN()-COLUMN($G$2),"-",
SUM(--(INDEX($B$2:$D$11,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$11,0),0)=INDEX($B$2:$D$11,MATCH(G$1,$A$2:$A$11,0),0))))
```

Comment: Would suggest to replace `IF( ROW(A1) >= COLUMN(A1), "-"` with `IF( $F2 >= G$1, "-"` to make the position of the solution table independent of the `data` table.

Comment: I think you're right, something goes wrong if you insert or delete rows or columns but I'm not assuming names are actually in order (although they may be) so maybe =IF(ROW()-ROW($G$2)>=COLUMN()-COLUMN($G$2),"-",
SUM(--(INDEX($B$2:$D$11,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$11,0),0)=INDEX($B$2:$D$11,MATCH(G$1,$A$2:$A$11,0),0))))

Comment: Good point not always the "names" are in order. However, in this kind of tables I would suggest they should as these tables could become very large and having the names in order makes easy to look for the values to be compared.